# Вычленить из твита хэштег

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-api

Вывожу список твитов в консоль, после чего под каждый твит нужно отдельно вывести его хэштег
использую метод regex+isMatch
Как результат твит, в котором хэштег выводится под твитом полностью, но раскладывается на 1 символ - 1 строка.

```
                var tweet = tweets[i].Text;
            var CreatedDate = tweets[i].CreatedDate.ToString("F");
            var TweetTime = DateTime.Parse(CreatedDate);
            var age = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TweetTime);
            Console.WriteLine(tweet);
            Console.WriteLine($"с момента создания прошло {age} времени");
            Console.WriteLine();
            var pattern = @"\s*#\s*";

            foreach(var sharp in tweet)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(tweet, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    Console.WriteLine(sharp);
            }
```

Comment: твитер, как мне кажется, совсем не причем. Приведите пример строки и желаемый результат.

Comment: "бла бла бла #хэштег бла бла" и под строкой должен быит выведен #хэштег @pincher1519

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод поиска соответствий - `Regex.Matches` и ещё немного модифицируйте паттерн, чтобы он включал не только решётку, но и само слово после неё.
Тогда `Regex.Matches`применённый к тексту из твита как раз и вернёт вам `MatchCollection` - коллекцию хэштегов из вашей строки.

```
string pattern = @"\s*#(\w+)\s*";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine("   " + match.Value);
}
```

Коротко об используемых элементах шаблона (из комментария [Anamnian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218976/anamnian)):

- \s - символ пробела
- * квантификатор, указывающий что пред. символ может встречаться от 0 до неограниченного числа раз
- # - обычная решетка
- () - обозначение группы символов   \w - любая буква
- + квантификатор, указывающий что пред символ может встречаться от 1 до неограниченного числа раз.

[Документация по регулярным выражениям](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/hs600312(v=vs.100))
[Кратко о регулярных выражениях](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.4.php)
[Справочник элементов языка регулярных выражений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Comment: Круто! сработало, но если вам не сложно - можете разобрать @"\s*#(\w+)\s*" - почему именно так?

Comment: @ТимурАлексеев я дополнил ответ ссылками. По второй более менее адекватно рассказывается, как оно всё работает.

Comment: @ТимурАлексеев \s - символ пробела, * - квантификатор, указывающий что пред. символ может встречаться от 0 до неограниченного числа раз, # - обычная решетка, ()- обозначение группы символов, \w - любая буква, + - квантификатор, указывающий что пред символ может встречаться от 1 до неограниченного числа раз.

Comment: Всё таки стоило добавить краткий ликбез по используемым символам, вам это ничего не стоит (можете взять мой пред. комментарий), а будущие пользователи будут благодарны- лучше прочитать на 1 странице, чем искать информацию по 3 ссылкам

Comment: @Anamnian огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Anamnian, ок, внёс. Спасибо за дополнение) но мне показалось, что лучше приучать людей к чтению документации, чем давать им готовые ответы.